# Do I need my own bsp layer and what should be placed there?

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux, yocto

I know that this might not be the best place to ask questions I wanted to ask but frankly even though I've browsed through a lot of resources I haven't found satisfying answers. I've been trying to learn how to use Yocto and therefore I've got some questions. (Btw if you know a better place to ask them please just let me know in a comment so I could the question there and remove this one, in order to not mess too much).

- In Embedded-Linux-Development-Using-Yocto-Project-Cookbook I've found that the good practice is to create my own bsp layer. Is it true in the case when my new-custom-bsp layer would be depending on e.g. meta-raspberrypi? So the meta-raspberrypi would be like a base for my bsp layer?
- Why should I define my own images?
- What should be placed in bsp layer? Linux kernel version? Uboot configuration? Device tree? What if I have my own kernel modules? Should I put them in bsp layer? What if I have modules that handle not the hardware on the board itself but rather hardware that can be plugged in the board? Wouldn't be better to put them into my-custom-distro layer?
- As for my my-custom-distro - what should be placed in this kind of layer? Running services? Loading drivers? User configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it true in the case when my new-custom-bsp layer would be depending
> on e.g. meta-raspberrypi? So the meta-raspberrypi would be like a base
> for my bsp layer?

Yes. Yes.

> Why should I define my own images?

Don't you want to control what is part of the image? You can use existing provided by the BSP layer if there are any otherwise.

> What should be placed in bsp layer? Linux kernel version? Uboot configuration? Device tree? What if I have my own kernel modules?

> As for my my-custom-distro - what should be placed in this kind of layer? Running services? Loading drivers? User configuration?

Whatever is needed to make it work on existing platform/board, so anything and/or everything from the above.